# Send header before execution ends

Tags: php, http-headers, output, flush, bluehost

On my development server (CentOS 6.3, PHP 5.3) this works fine:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
header('Location: http://test.hooshmarketing.com/tools/test/test_pretty_output.php');
//here a long script keeps executing in the background a few seconds
```

this works fine too

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
echo "foo"; //I see foo on the browser and...
sleep (15);
echo "bar"; //... about 15 seconds later I see bar on the browser
```

and this

```
ob_start();
echo "foo"; //foo is written...
sleep(10); 
ob_flush(); //...about 10 second later, foo is sent
echo "bar"; //bar is written...
sleep(10); 
ob_end_flush(); //...about 10 second later, bar is sent
```

On my contractor's production server (bluehost PHP 5.2 shared hosting) none of the three examples work. Nothing is sent to the client until the script finishes executing. I tried setting `ini_set('output_buffering', '0')` and `output_buffering = Off` on the script folder's php.ini file but no luck. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ob_implicit_flush(true);` then you no need to call the `flush();` but you have to use the **ob_flush();**.

ob_flush(); brings out data from application initiated buffer. PHP internally has CGI buffer, ob_implicit_flush(true); will turn on the implicit flushing, which does not use CGI buffer and which uses application initiated buffer.

So once you are using ob_implicit_flush(true); then you have to use ob_flush();

I hope this helps.

Comment: It covers only one case, and it didn't work anyway. I'm pretty sure all cases are related: no output until the end of the script, no matter what. And, are you sure? http://php.net/ob_implicit_flush says: "Implicit flushing will result in a flush operation after every output call, so that explicit calls to flush() will no longer be needed.")

Comment: alright, but still didn't solve the problem :-( (And curiously I don't need to do neither flush nor ob_flush in my development server)

Comment: yes, but you have to use ob_flush() for every print/echo, if you are using ob_implicit_flush(true);.